# Getting started with developing for Chrome

Tags: java, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I have been asked by my friend to make an application for Chrome and it requires me to have context-sensitive menus as below:
[image]

I have never really made anything for Chrome before and I have a few questions regarding it:

1. I will have to develop a `plug-in`, right ?
2. If so, is there a specific set of rules I have to follow ?

I know I can use [GWT](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/) to compile Java to JavaScript
3. This context sensitive menu is the same as `JPopupMenu` ?

The application I want to develop is simple:
Copy some text,
right-click, click on the context sensitive menu
apply simple Caesar's cipher to the text
open a new `JFrame` with `JtextArea` in it to display the encrypted text.

Comment: 1. No, you will be developing an extension. 3. I suggest to stick to vanilla JavaScript, because there are plenty of examples in the documentation and on Stack Overflow which aid you in the development of the extension. You just have to know the relevant API. See [`chrome.contextMenus`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contextMenus.html) for creating context menu entries, and [`chrome.windows.create`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/windows.html#method-create) to create a window and [Getting started](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/getstarted.html) to, well, get started!

Comment: @RobW Post this as an answer so I can accept it :) add more stuff if you want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. What you're creating is called an "[extension](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/index.html)", not a "plug-in". A browser extension is written using HTML, CSS and Javascript, and got access to APIs for direct interaction with the browser.
   [Plug-ins](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/npapi.html), on the other hand, are compiled binaries such as Flash and Java.
2. 
3. Drop the idea of using GWT for Chrome extensions. It makes development of the extension harder, not easier ([open issue](https://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=5577)).
   Especially because you'll find plenty of vanilla JavaScript examples and tutorials in [the documentation](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/devguide.html) and Stack Overflow.

You just have to know the relevant APIs:

> Copy some text,
>   right-click, click on the context sensitive menu

Use [`chrome.contextMenus`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contextMenus.html). There's no need to copy, the selected text is available in the callback ([examples](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contextMenus.html#samples)).

> apply simple Caesar's cipher to the text

Create a JavaScript function to achieve this.

> open a new JFrame with JtextArea in it to display the encrypted text.

Create a new window using [`chrome.windows.create`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/windows.html#method-create). You could include an extra HTML page in your extension, and use the [message passing APIs](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging.html) to populate the text field, but since you appear to be a complete newbie, I show a simple copy-paste method to create and populate this window:

```
function displayText(title, text) {
    var escapeHTML = function(s) { return (s+'').replace(/</g, '&lt;'); };
    var style = '*{width:100%;height:100%;box-sizing:border-box}';
    style += 'html,body{margin:0;padding:0;}';
    style += 'textarea{display:block;}';
    var html = '<!DOCTYPE html>';
    html += '<html><head><title>';
    html += escapeHTML(title);
    html += '</title>';
    html += '<style>' + style + '</style>';
    html += '</head><body><textarea>';
    html += escapeHTML(text);
    html += '</body></html>'

    var url = 'data:text/html,' + encodeURIComponent(html);
    chrome.windows.create({
        url: url,
        focused: true
    });
}
```

Don't forget to read [Getting started](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/getstarted.html) to learn more about the extension's infrastructure.

Answer (score 0):

Check out Google Chrome Extensions [Chrome Extensions](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/index.html)

The Getting Started will help you [Getting Started](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/getstarted.html)

You will find a section on how to use Context Menus.